# How to make a TCP socket time out

Tags: socket, timeout

For network catastrophe simulations of our server environment, we are looking for a way to intentionally timeout a TCP socket. Are there any simple ways for existing sockets? Also, little C test-case program would be a plus.

We have already tried putting down network interfaces during TCP buffer reading, and reading from disconnected mounted resources (samba).

Out test server is Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To cause an exiting connection to timeout you can use `iptables`.  Just enable a `DROP` rule on the port you want to disable.  So to simulate a timeout for your Samaba server, while an active connection is up, execute the following on the server:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 445 -j DROP
```

The `DROP` target will not reply with a `RST` packet or `ICMP` error to the packet's sender.  The client will stop receiving packets from the server and eventually timeout.

Depending on if/how you have `iptables` configured, you may want to insert the rule higher into the `INPUT` ruleset.

Comment: Tried this using netcat ( to listen/send data ) and waited forever... no timeout :/ And I can confirm the data was dropped. I even changed `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time` to a really small number

Comment: @er453r try enabling verbose output with `ncat -v` to see what exactly `ncat` is doing.  It took me 2m7.291s on a vanilla Ubuntu 12.04 install to timeout

Comment: right - I wasn't sending anything through the socket during that first test. I've finally mastered the timeouts and described them in detail below :)

Answer (score 21):

The first answer is correct, but I've discovered how these timeouts work, so you could observe and test them (don't forget to block the port!).

There are 4 most interesting kernel parameters that deal with TCP timeouts:

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_intvl
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_probes
/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_retries2
```

Now there are 2 scenarios:

1. The socket is opened and trying to transmit - then (if there is no response from the other side), system retries `tcp_retries2` times. With the default value of retires it takes somewhere over 2 minutes and the socket times out.
2. The socket is opened and idle - then keepalive limits are interesting. With an idle socket system will wait `tcp_keepalive_time` seconds, and after that try `tcp_keepalive_probes` times to send a TCP KEEPALIVE in intervals of `tcp_keepalive_intvl` seconds. And only after that all failes the socket times out.

Comment: also, you can monitor this timeouts using `netstat -o`